# Joomla K2 - Get K2 image URL

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

So i've did this into my template `php` file **to show different header between `Item` and `Itemlist` views**.

```
<!-- BLOG HEADER RENDER -->
<?php $com=JRequest::getCmd( 'option'); $view=JRequest::getCmd( 'view'); $img=JRequest::getCmd( 'CatItemImage'); if($com=='com_k2' && $view!='item' ): ?>
<div class="headerblog">
     <h2>Lorem Ipsum <span>dolore algo mais...</span> </h2>

</div>
<?php else: ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img ;?>" width="100%" height="380px" />
<?php endif ?>
```

The condition works well, but I am having problems to get CatItemImage from `Item` view.

- **Joomla Version:** 3.2
- **K2 Version:** 2.6.7

Anybody could help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, just seen you're using Joomla 3.2 and therefore you should not use `JRequest` as it's deprecated. Have a look at this: http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput . You should also not put this code in your template index.php file. You should create a template override for the K2 views like so: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yep, I use `JRequest`, the cleanify of my editor gives a space and I didn't see in Copy&Paste. But it's already without space.

Comment: Made a few changes to my comment above, please look^^

Comment: @Lodder **1)** Thanks, I will try with `JInput`. **2)** When I said my template, I mean my Joomla template file, inside of my module position. :) **3)** I dunno how this could help me, since I am stucked about how I get K2 ItemImage.

Comment: to get the image, try using `$this->item->image`

Comment: Already tried before, only gets `/`.